# Using Container.DataItem with an If statement within <% %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, literals

I have the following code in a c# aspx page:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a <% if(((Dictionary<string, string>)Container.DataItem)["type"]==Session["type"]){%> class="active"<%}%>
```

This code is causing the following error.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.ComponentModel.Container' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem'
```

Why is that and how can I make a conditional statement that uses the `Container.DataItem`? `Container.DataItem` works perfectly when used within a `<%# %>` however putting the `if` statement within the `<%# %>` causes the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have something like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# ((Dictionary<string, string>)Container.DataItem)["type"].Equals(Session["type"]) ? 
"<a class='active'>mylink</a>" : 
"<a>mylink</a>" %>
```

or

```
<ItemTemplate>
<a class='<%# ((Dictionary<string, string>)Container.DataItem)["type"].Equals(Session["type"]) ? 
"active" : string.Empty" %>'>my link </a>
```

**EDIT**
Added the Equals to the solution

Comment: For some reason the conditional statement is always resolving in 'false' and always giving the 'false' result.

Comment: Ok solved it! instead of `==` I needed to use `.Equals()`. Awesome solution thanks a lot mate!

Comment: It's a string derived from a `KeyValuePair` within a `Dictionary Generic`